# Will a Japanese visa refusal hurt my chances at a US tourist visa?

Tags: visas, passports, visa-refusals, sri-lankan-citizens

I am From Sri Lanka (Asia).

I applied to Australia 2 to 3 years back for a tourist visa but I was rejected.

This year, 2016, I got visas to go to Germany, France, Switzerland and also India. This month I applied for Japan but I was rejected with a "C". Supposedly this is not a major reason, just a slight problem in the application.

After Japan, I wanted to go to the USA for a holiday. Will the Japanese visa denial mean that I have no chance to get a USA visa?

if I go to China or some other country again and then apply for a US visa will I have a better chance?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: OP, I rewrote the question to bring out what I thought was your actual question while keeping the relevant information. If you disagree, you can revert (undo) my changes or make your own.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You are asking for several things. If you just stick to the current title (Will a Japanese visa refusal hurt my chances at a US tourist visa?), and remove the stuff not related to that, I will vote to reopen. In the current state it's too confusing and there's too much seemingly unrelated information and too many questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's extremely hard to predict your chances of getting a US visa but as an Indian, I can attest that it's quiet hard for the citizens in subcontinent to get a US visitor visa. It's probably because people in India, Bangladesh, Sri Lanka, etc. often overstay their welcome and end up being illegal immigrants. With the political climate in the US generally negative towards immigration, it's hard to speculate if you will get your visa or not.

While you do have some positives going for you(such as your trip in Europe), the recent rejection from the Japanese and the earlier rejection Australian embassy doesn't help. That being said, it's impossible for any of us here to even guess if you'll get your visa or not. The US visa process is an interview based process, a lot depends on your actual purpose of stay, your current income and most importantly how you actually answer the questions. A little bit of confidence can actually make a lot of change.  But the only way you can find out is that if you apply. Do remember that it's generally harder for people in the "third world" to get a US visa. But there shouldn't be any harm in applying. Keep your fingers crossed and apply.